# if condition not working properly in html js

Tags: javascript, html

in if condition i get value max 10 min 9 when compare its true and exe how its possible

```
    for(var r=1;r<n;r++) 
    {  c=0;
       max=table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
       if (max<minimum) 
       {  
         alert("if max"+max+" minimum"+minimum );
         minimum = max;
         alert(minimum);
         location = r+1;
       }
       else
       { 
          minimum=minimum;
          alert("else minimum"+minimum);``
       }
    }
}
```

Thank you

give me solutions to find correct answer or else i need code for highlight in table cell which cells are all have minimum value in a table

Comment: when and how you init "minimum"?

Comment: minimum=minimum; makes no sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max=table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
```

InnerHTML is a string. In order to do comparison you need to convert it to a number with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

```
max = parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parseInt()` method because the verification will be done on a string:

```
max=parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
```